# Proof by contrapositive...enough to show for one case of the interval?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

I have a question regarding proof by contrapositive.

I want to show that $A \implies B$.

Proof by contrapositive would work like $\neg B \implies \neg A$.

Is it enough to show that this holds for one specific example? In other words, I dont have to show it for the whole set of possible parameters, right? If I´d have to make a case distinction, would it be a problem to assume different disjunct set of parameters for each case?

$\quad$

To illustrate what I mean:

Imagine I assume $f(x) = c$ minimizes something (means its optimal), if it has a certain value $\alpha$.

$f(x) = c$ is optimal$\implies f(x) = c =\alpha$.

Now, proof my contrapositve would look like this:

$f(x) = c \neq \alpha\implies f(x) = c$ is not optimal

$\quad$

Now, for this proof by contrapositve to work we first assume $f(x) = c \neq \alpha$. We´d have to check to different cases.

1. $f(x) = c < \alpha$
2. $f(x) = c > \alpha$

Next thing we would have to show, that this implies $f(x) = c$ is not optimal.

Imagine I choose the first case and assume this minimizes the loss. Now, I can show that if I increase the value $c$ a little bit, the loss gets smaller. That means it was not optimal. But if I decrease the value, the loss gets bigger. But this only holds if $\alpha < 0.5$, f.e.

From my understanding, this shows is sufficient for the first case.

My problem is, If we now go to the second case, we´d basically have to assume the opposite.
If we decrease $c$ the loss gets smaller and if we increase $c$ the loss gets bigger but only if $\alpha > 0.5$.

I´m not sure if this is actually allowed to assume $\alpha > 0.5$ for one case  and $\alpha < 0.5$.

I dont have to show it for all $\alpha$, right? One case where it doesnt hold its enough? And the fact that we have to assume different $\alpha$ for the case distinction is no problem in itself?

Comment: If you "assume $f(x) = c$ minimizes something (means its optimal), if it has a certain value $\alpha$", then is the arrow in "$f(x) = c$ is optimal$\implies f(x) = c =\alpha$" pointing the wrong direction?

Comment: The problem I´m refering to basically goes like " Show that the constant f(x) = c that optimizes the quantile loss given a specifiy $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is the $\alpha$-quantile." So, I´m not even sure if it would be possible to state equivalence between the statemens $F(c) = \alpha$ and that f(x) = c minimizes the quantile loss.

Comment: From the task given I assumed that $A:$ $f(x)$ minimizes the quantile loss and $B:$ $c$ is the $\alpha$-quantile. So if we assume $f(x)$ minimizes the quantile loss, this implies that its the $\alpha$-quantile.

Comment: The negation of "$f(x)=c=\alpha$" should be "$f(x)\ne c$ or $c\ne \alpha$".

Comment: @peterwhy I think thats what I´ve written. "Now, proof my contrapositve would look like this:  $f(x) = c \neq \alpha \implies$ f(x) = c is not optimal". $f(x) = c$ is fixed. Just in case its not equal to $\alpha$, its not the optimum.